# Assigned Files in entries won't get synced on localization

Tags: entries, assets, localization, language

I've got an entry-type, which has images and sound-files assigned through an asset-field.
When i create an entry, those fields won't be synced in my other languages, even though the mark for "This field is translatable" is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this field to be synced (always same assets selected) across your locales you actually have to *uncheck* "This field is translatable".